# Skip primitive/wrapper/String type when using Retrofit with SimpleXML Converter

Tags: java, xml-serialization, retrofit, simple-framework

When using

```
new Persister().write("test", System.out);
```

I keep getting

```
<string>test</string>
```

However, the API I'm connecting to using Retrofit needs pure value if a primitive/wrapper/String variable is being sent. I cannot have a root tag that would enclose this whole structure - then it works fine.

I want to achieve simply `test` out of `new Persister().write("test", System.out);`